# Haskell: Different ways to convert division of Integers to Double

Tags: haskell

Say I want to divide 5 (Integer) by 3 (Integer), and I want my answer to be a Double. What different ways are there to do this in Haskell?

Comment: you can try to make all combination of `fromInteger` and `quot`, `div` and `/` and see how far you come, and see what results you expect or not - especially negative numbers will give you some insight in how `quot` and `div` differ. you can also add your own division algorithms if you have not enough combinations at your hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common approaches involve converting the `Integer`s to `Double`s and then dividing them. You can do this through `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`, which takes any value of an integer-like type (e.g. `Integer`) and turns it into any number-like type (e.g. `Double`).

```
let five, three :: Double
    five = fromIntegral (5 :: Integer)
    three = fromIntegral (3 :: Integer)
in five / three
```

Note that `fromIntegral = fromInteger . toInteger`, where `toInteger` is part of the `Integral` class (`toInteger` turns a value of an integer-like type into the corresponding `Integer` value), and `fromInteger` is part of the `Num` class (`fromInteger` turns an `Integer` value into a value of any desired number-like type). In this case, because you already have an `Integer` value, you could use `fromInteger` instead of `fromIntegral`.

A much less common approach would be to somehow create a `Rational` number and converting it:

```
let five, three, fiveThirds :: Rational
    five = toRational (5 :: Integer)
    three = toRational (3 :: Integer)
    fiveThirds = five / three
in fromRational fiveThirds
```

The other way to do create `Rational`s (somehow) depends on which standard you're using. If you've imported `Ratio` (Haskell 98) or `Data.Ratio` (Haskell 2010), you can also use the `(%) :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> Ratio a` operator:

```
let five, three :: Integer
    fiveThirds :: Rational
    five = 5
    three = 3
    fiveThirds = five % three
in (fromRational fiveThirds :: Double)
```

Answer (score 1):

The type signature of `/` is:

```
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
```

This means that, if you want to get a `Double` from `/` you will need to provide doubles, not integers. Therefore, I would suggest using a function such as `fromIntegral`, as shown below:

```
fromIntegral (5 :: Integer) / fromIntegral (2 :: Integer) == 2.5
```